# Is there an efficient way to load png-Images into a TImage object in FMX while it’s running?

Tags: delphi, png, firemonkey

In order to show many different sized PNG-Images (with transparent background) i Need to load them out of the resources of the program. In VCL, this is easy as you are able to simply use the TPngImage to load and assign them. In Firemonkey this doesn’t exist, so I need another way to do this. Is there a function in FMX in order to do that? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to use TImage?

Comment: Yes, i tried to load the png into the timage, but this doesn't work in firemonkey, but in delphi. Also i need to change the look of the image while the program is running, so i need to reassign the image

Comment: @Dirty VCL uses different `TGraphic` classes for different image formats (`TPngImage` for PNG, etc). FMX uses [`TBitmap`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Graphics.TBitmap) for everything and it certainly handles PNG (see [Supported Image Formats](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Graphics.TBitmapCodecManager#Supported_Image_Formats)). FMX's [`TImage`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Objects.TImage) uses `TBitmap`. So, what is the *actual* problem you are having with it?

Comment: @remy lebeau As soon as i try to load the png into the bitmap, it delets the transparency as well, so i need a way to actually make it remind the alpha channel i guess

Comment: @Dirty alpha/transparency is built into the PNG format, I seriously doubt `TBitmap` is ignoring it. Especially since PNG is one of the few formats that `TBitmap` supports across multiple platforms. Please edit your question to include a [mcve] that is not working the way you want.

Comment: @remy lebeau Thanks as first, i will edit tha question

Comment: @Dirty Please also include the version of Delphi you are using. Especially with FMX everything is very dependent on this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this function:

```
uses
  FMX.Surfaces, FMX.Graphics;
(...)

function PngToBmp(PNG: TStream): TBitmap;
var
  surf: TBitmapSurface;
begin
  Assert(Assigned(PNG));

  surf := TBitmapSurface.Create;
  try
    if TBitmapCodecManager.LoadFromStream(PNG, surf) then
    begin
      Result := TBitmap.Create;
      Result.Assign(surf);
    end else
      Result := nil;
  finally
    surf.DisposeOf;
  end;
end;
```

And how to use it:

```
bmp := PngToBmp(strPng);
if Assigned(bmp) then
  try
    Image1.Bitmap.Assign(bmp);
  finally
    bmp.DisposeOf;
  end;
```

Conversion to TBitmap can be omitted of course, because TImage can load images from TStream.